# Noise floor raising at high RF input power after filtering

Tags: rf, filter, noise

I have a USRP b205mini with AD9364 transceiver. When it receives a very high RX input of about -5 dBm at different frequencies, **not** in the original RX range, the noise level raises slightly. The RX is configured to 2.406 GHz at 20M sampling rate. The Tx it receives comes as a CW at 1 GHZ or 3 GHZ and should be filtered by the receiver. What really causes the noise floor to raise? Performance of filters, saturation of amplifier or else? Thank you!

Below you can see what happened.

Idle.
[image: Idle]

Now transmitting CW of -5 dBm at 1 GHZ (Rx configured to 2.406 GHZ). Note the slightly raised noise level.

[image: After]

The difference between these two states. Red - before CW input (idle), blue - CW is on.
[image]

Comment: Your experiment may demonstrate *reciprocal mixing*. Phase noise of oscillators (either in the TX or your RX) could be the cause.

Comment: Maybe. Put please note that the peak in the middle (2406 MHz) caused by natural LO leak of the USRP. This is not a real signal.

Comment: I think this article explains it well
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3813

Comment: Asked about it here: https://ez.analog.com/wide-band-rf-transceivers/design-support/f/q-a/106666/noise-floor-raising-at-high-rf-input-power-after-filtering